# Android volley post request with json object in body and getting response in String

Tags: android, post, android-volley

How i can send `json` object in body and get response in string?

```
Body:
{
     "username": "Shozib@gmail.com",
     "password": "Shozib123"
  }
```

Response:
"`k5ix28k9ikhtcqys4swatnfvohrcg0lp`"

Comment: Hi Shozib, please provide additional details and perhaps a small code example.  What have you tried?  Can you provide more information on the expected behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Try This**

```
try {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    jsonBody.put("username", "Shozib@gmail.com");
    jsonBody.put("password", "Shozib123");
    final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("LOG_RESPONSE", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("LOG_RESPONSE", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String responseString = "";
            if (response != null) {
                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
            }
            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks! but it is returning request code but not actual string it should return

Comment: No in the success response it will give string... check is it printing on successful or error

Comment: StringRequeat will return string in the success

Comment: I got it, in above code we are overriding "responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);", if i am commenting the parseNetworkRespose it is returning actual string

Comment: Agree my answer by clicking tick.. happy to help you